# Using SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR Environment Variable does not retain generated metadata

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

When setting ***SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR*** using `SET SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=path_to_some_folder`, I get a message saying that ***SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR*** is deprecated, use ***SF_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR*** instead. I set the updated variable to retain metadata but in both cases, I don't see any metadata or folder created in the directory I set, for any command I run, although I see the following warning message :
[image]

I am using Windows and tried with Command Prompt (cmd.exe) and Powershell.